# $K_4$ or n vertices without triangles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

For which minimal $m(n)$ any graph on $m$ vertices contains either a complete subgraph on 4 vertices $K_4$ or $n$-vertices subgraph without triangles? I know a quadratic upper bound $2n^2$, but I am not sure it is tight.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it seems to me like this was more or less resolved by Wolfovitz ["K4-Free Graphs Without Large Induced Triangle-Free Subgraphs"]. If I'm reading right, older bounds by Krivelevich and then Wolfovitz shows that $n^2/\log^{C_1}(n)\leq m(n)\leq C_2\cdot n^2/\log\log(n)$ for some constants $C_1,C_2>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jason.